# Prettier's import order sorting correctly on save, but eslint complains

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, eslint, prettier

I historically have used [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import) to manage the linting of my import block, I'm trying prettier's built in import sorting.  I want anything starting with `react` to be first, then all third party modules, then all absolute modules.  So a block like this should be valid:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Text, TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
import { useBottomSheetInternal } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import { Column, PillTabs, Row } from '../../../../common/components';
import { theme } from '../../../../theme';
import { Steps } from '..';
import { Search } from './Search';
```

I've adjusted my .prettierrc.js to look like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  arrowParens: 'avoid',
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: 'all',
  // sort imports
  importOrderSeparation: false,
  importOrderSortSpecifiers: true,
  importOrderCaseInsensitive: true,
  importOrder: [
    '^react(.*)$', // All react imports first
    '<THIRD_PARTY_MODULES>', // Then node modules
    '^src/(.*)$', // All local files from src
    '^(.*)/(?!generated)(.*)/(.*)$', // Everything not generated
    '^(.*)/generated/(.*)$', // Everything generated
    '^[./]', // Absolute path imports
  ],
};
```

And my eslint is faily simple:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: ['@react-native-community', 'prettier'],
  rules: {
    // Eslint rules:
    'space-in-brackets': 0,
    'prettier/prettier': [1],

    // React rules:
    'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 0,

    // React native community overrides:
    'react-native/no-inline-styles': 0,

    // Typescript rules:
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': [1],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-shadow': 0,
  },
};
```

However, the above block shows a linting error:

[image]

Unfortunately, the prettier import linting errors are not that useful.  The error says:

> Delete `';⏎import·{·useBottomSheetInternal·}·from·'@gorhom/bottom-sheet`eslintprettier/prettier

On auto-save, the eslint and prettier seem to be fighting, as it reformats to put the `@gorhom/bottom-sheet` import first, then reformats again to put the `react` block first, creating an eslint-prettier fighting flicker.

What am I doing wrong with the way I've set up the import order in prettierrc that eslint is not understanding that I want all react imports first?